# How to INNER JOIN multiple values

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name as song_name
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.song_name_id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.id = '..'
```

I get following error when t2.id column has two id's like this 6,12. Obviously, works, when record t2.id (nvarchar) is only one. How can I make it work with two/multiple?

Error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '6,12' to data type int.
```

Comment: Don't store CSV data in your table.  One ID per record if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The error is possibly because `table1.song_name_id` and `table2.id` have different data types. Please ensure they are of same type or use `convert` function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Store CSV data in your table however a temporary solution is given below.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name as song_name
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON (t1.song_name_id = left(t2.id,1))
or(t1.song_name_id = right(t2.id,1)) 
WHERE t1.id = '..'
```

Different Approach should be handled if the table2 id column contains more than 2 values separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

As Bishakh Ghosh mentioned, you really should be joining on fields with same types, and also as Coder1991 said, you really shouldn't stored comma separated values in a single field.

Given that the field is in the state that it is, you can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) to find whether or not t2.id contains the value in t1.song_name_id.

In the below example, the additional commas will allow for "6,12" to become ",6,12," and song_name_id in the like statement will become "%,6,%" which will then find a match.

```
SELECT
    t1.*, 
    t2.name as song_name
FROM
    table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON 
    ',' + t2.id + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),t1.song_name_id) + ',%'
WHERE
    t1.id = '..'
```